# How can I prevent a value from being rendered in the group header when using renderCell on a column in Material UI’s DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

codesandbox replicating this issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-gagarin-jgcnfl?file=/demo.tsx:563-672

relevant piece of code that renders this contrived example of 'asdf' for the Id row.:

```
{
  field: "id",
  headerName: "ID",
  width: 100,
  renderCell: (params) => <div>"asdf"</div>
}
```

And as you can see "asdf" render at on the expandable group header. How can I hide this and only show it for the rows once you expand the group. Note: I need it to return JSX, so I cannot use `valueFormatter`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
renderCell: ({ rowNode }) => (
    rowNode.type === "group" ? null : <div>asdf</div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help that worked. Would you know how to handle the case when using `valueFormatter`. In my case I am doing `valueFormarmatter: ({value}) => formatNumber(value)` and `formatNumber` returns a dash `-` when `value` is undefined so it shows a dash in the group header. I guess the only solution is to use CSS to hide the non-first group header values?

Comment: can u give an example?
(I'm not sure I understand, what and how do u want to format)

Comment: see this codesandbox of a more simpler example: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-greider-8du7z2?file=/demo.tsx:2106-2225

Notice 'asdf' is visible in the group header for the Name column. I want it to be hidden in the group header ( but visible in the rows once you expand). I'm thinking css is the through the `sx` prop is the only way?

Comment: u can use "renderCell" & "formatValue" togethaa, render cell will receive the formatted value
```
valueFormatter: () => "asdf",
      renderCell: ({ rowNode, value }) => (
        rowNode.type === "group" ? null : <div>{value}</div>
      ),
˙```